# How can get the json in the url?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

I can get the json data in the url with browser.

```
https://stock.xueqiu.com/v5/stock/finance/us/income.json?symbol=ASX&type=all&is_detail=true&count=5
```

Opened in chrome.
[image]

Opened in firefox.
[image]

Try to crawl the web with requests library:

```
import requests
url="https://stock.xueqiu.com/v5/stock/finance/us/income.json?symbol=ASX&type=all&is_detail=true&count=5"
headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0"}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
<Response [400]>
```

Try to crawl the web with selenium library:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
url="https://stock.xueqiu.com/v5/stock/finance/us/income.json?symbol=ASX&type=all&is_detail=true&count=5"
browser.get(url)
browser.page_source
'<html><head></head><body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
{"error_description":"遇到错误，请刷新页面或者重新登录帐号后再试","error_uri":"/v5/stock
/finance/us/income.json","error_code":"400016"}</pre></body></html>'
```

How can get the json in the url?
I have never login the website,clear all caches in browser, and open the json's url ,it encountered error message,open the `https://xueqiu.com/snowman/S/ASX/detail#/GSLRB` in browser ,wait for a moment and  open the `https://stock.xueqiu.com/v5/stock/finance/us/income.json?symbol=ASX&type=all&is_detail=true&count=5` again,all data shown in browser.

Comment: The URL cannot be opened in a browser.

Comment: My uploaded image shows it can be opened in a browser surely.

Comment: But not in my browser. I see the same error message as your scripts. Have you previously logged in?

Comment: Never login,i clear all caches in browser, and open the json's url  ,it encountered error message,open the `https://xueqiu.com/snowman/S/ASX/detail#/GSLRB` and open the `https://stock.xueqiu.com/v5/stock/finance/us/income.json?symbol=ASX&type=all&is_detail=true&count=5` again,all data shown in browser.

Comment: Although you may believe you've cleared everything, either that's not the case, or the website is doing something else to detect where your request is coming from. Google says your error message (and mine) translates to "Encountered an error, please refresh the page or log in to your account again and try again" - that seems to suggest you are in fact logged in. Possibly the server does something fancy to fingerprint your browser, but it seems more likely you're overlooking some cookie or similar issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page `https://stock.xueqiu.com/v5/stock/finance/us/income.json?symbol=ASX&type=all&is_detail=true&count=5` requires the cookies of page `https://xueqiu.com/snowman/S/ASX/detail#/GSLRB`, so a possible solution is to use [`requests.Session`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Session):

```py
import requests
import pprint

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0"
}
url1 = "https://xueqiu.com/snowman/S/ASX/detail#/GSLRB"
url2 = "https://stock.xueqiu.com/v5/stock/finance/us/income.json?symbol=ASX&type=all&is_detail=true&count=5"

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)
    s.get(url1)
    r = s.get(url2)
    pprint.pprint(r.json())
```

Output:

```
{'data': {'annual_settle_date': '12-31',
          'currency': 'TWD',
          'currency_name': '新台币',
          'last_report_name': '2020年FY',
          'list': [{'ctime': 1617756162000,
                    'ed': '2020-12-31',
                    'gross_profit': [77984268000.0, 0.21261555583679398],
                    'income_from_co': [28651900000.0, 0.5683716810816832],
                    'income_from_co_before_it': [35768798000.0,
                                                 0.536472869131111],
                    'income_from_co_before_tax_si': [3302123000.0,
                                                     -0.18326588478789202],
                    'income_tax': [7116898000.0, 0.4201853191801001],
                    'interest_expense': [3459511000.0, -0.1769721855785621],
                    'interest_income': [None, None],
                    'marketing_selling_etc': [23805768000.0,
                                              0.06327703424731415],
                    'net_income': [28651900000.0, 0.5683716810816832],
                    'net_income_atcss': [26970580000.0, 0.5808702054928813],
                    'net_income_atms_interest': [1681320000.0,
                                                 0.39185114911413654],
                    'net_interest_expense': [3459511000.0, -0.1769721855785621],
                    'operating_income': [31919063000.0, 0.6751497051555505],
                    'othr_revenues': [None, None],
                    'preferred_dividend': [0.0, None],
                    'rad_expenses': [19302418000.0, 0.04931054799005009],
                    'report_annual': 2020,
                    'report_date': 1609344000005,
                    'report_name': '2020年FY',
                    'report_type_code': 596001,
                    'revenue': [476978710000.0, 0.15440289651985575],
                    'sales_cost': [398994442000.0, 0.1436720014683004],
                    'sd': '2020-01-01',
                    'share_of_earnings_of_affiliate': [547612000.0,
                                                       2.004317651899602],
                    'total_basic_earning_common_ps': [6.32, 0.576059850374065],
                    'total_compre_income': [29147213000.0, 1.097230498820186],
                    'total_compre_income_atcss': [27440726000.0,
                                                  1.0911704872321188],
                    'total_compre_income_atms': [1706487000.0,
                                                 1.1997360038877551],
                    'total_dlt_earnings_common_ps': [6.17, 0.578005115089514],
                    'total_net_income_atcss': [26970580000.0,
                                               0.5808702054928813],
                    'total_operate_expenses': [46065205000.0,
                                               0.017872987914466523],
                    'total_operate_expenses_si': [-502492000.0,
                                                  -2.871095306361825],
                    'total_revenue': [476978710000.0, 0.15440289651985575]},
                   {'ctime': 1617756162000,
                    'ed': '2019-12-31',
                    'gross_profit': [64310793000.0, 0.05146478143258062],
                    'income_from_co': [18268565000.0, -0.33385504808890537],
                    'income_from_co_before_it': [23279811000.0,
                                                 -0.27108630126460664],
                    'income_from_co_before_tax_si': [4043082000.0,
                                                     -0.5491069252894362],
                    'income_tax': [5011246000.0, 0.11031160979747058],
                    'interest_expense': [4203395000.0, 0.17800199033641506],
                    'interest_income': [None, None],
                    'marketing_selling_etc': [22389055000.0,
                                              0.14507365860389632],
                    'net_income': [18268565000.0, -0.33385504808890537],
                    'net_income_atcss': [17060591000.0, -0.34934699164069516],
                    'net_income_atms_interest': [1207974000.0,
                                                 0.0036441041286553208],
                    'net_interest_expense': [4203395000.0, 0.17800199033641506],
                    'operating_income': [19054454000.0, -0.18748112827671856],
                    'othr_revenues': [None, None],
                    'preferred_dividend': [0.0, None],
                    'rad_expenses': [18395334000.0, 0.22940460538165353],
                    'report_annual': 2019,
                    'report_date': 1577721600004,
                    'report_name': '2019年FY',
                    'report_type_code': 596001,
                    'revenue': [413182184000.0, 0.11342124122766711],
                    'sales_cost': [348871391000.0, 0.1256480464382964],
                    'sd': '2019-01-01',
                    'share_of_earnings_of_affiliate': [182275000.0,
                                                       1.379546647121047],
                    'total_basic_earning_common_ps': [4.01,
                                                      -0.3511326860841424],
                    'total_compre_income': [13897954000.0, -0.4769636105391466],
                    'total_compre_income_atcss': [13122185000.0,
                                                  -0.48782400909960205],
                    'total_compre_income_atms': [775769000.0,
                                                 -0.18444496307883804],
                    'total_dlt_earnings_common_ps': [3.91,
                                                     -0.35584843492586493],
                    'total_net_income_atcss': [17060591000.0,
                                               -0.34934699164069516],
                    'total_operate_expenses': [45256339000.0,
                                               0.20005272067674873],
                    'total_operate_expenses_si': [268555000.0,
                                                  1.7227322024958085],
                    'total_revenue': [413182184000.0, 0.11342124122766711]},
                   {'ctime': 1560942703000,
                    'ed': '2019-03-31',
                    'gross_profit': [11385000000.0, 0.09597612629957643],
                    'income_from_co': [2230000000.0, -0.053480475382003394],
                    'income_from_co_before_it': [2635000000.0,
                                                 -0.3021716101694915],
                    'income_from_co_before_tax_si': [1462000000.0,
                                                     4.601532567049809],
                    'income_tax': [405000000.0, -0.7147887323943662],
                    'interest_expense': [None, None],
                    'interest_income': [None, None],
                    'marketing_selling_etc': [5137000000.0, 0.5580831058538065],
                    'net_income': [2230000000.0, -0.053480475382003394],
                    'net_income_atcss': [2043000000.0, -0.025286259541984733],
                    'net_income_atms_interest': [187000000.0,
                                                 -0.28076923076923077],
                    'net_interest_expense': [966000000.0, 1.7058823529411764],
                    'operating_income': [1327000000.0, -0.6648143470573377],
                    'othr_revenues': [None, None],
                    'preferred_dividend': [0.0, None],
                    'rad_expenses': [3955000000.0, 0.4252252252252252],
                    'report_annual': 2019,
                    'report_date': 1553961600000,
                    'report_name': '2019年Q1',
                    'report_type_code': 596003,
                    'revenue': [88861000000.0, 0.3678077763753348],
                    'sales_cost': [77476000000.0, 0.4195463373520466],
                    'sd': '2019-01-01',
                    'share_of_earnings_of_affiliate': [-154000000.0,
                                                       0.6531531531531531],
                    'total_basic_earning_common_ps': [0.48,
                                                      -0.02040816326530614],
                    'total_compre_income': [None, None],
                    'total_compre_income_atcss': [None, None],
                    'total_compre_income_atms': [None, None],
                    'total_dlt_earnings_common_ps': [0.46,
                                                     -0.04166666666666659],
                    'total_net_income_atcss': [2043000000.0,
                                               -0.025286259541984733],
                    'total_operate_expenses': [10058000000.0,
                                               0.5644734795458081],
                    'total_operate_expenses_si': [None, None],
                    'total_revenue': [88861000000.0, 0.3678077763753348]},
                   {'ctime': 1617756162000,
                    'ed': '2018-12-31',
                    'gross_profit': [61163050000.0, 0.15987892878726956],
                    'income_from_co': [27424309000.0, 0.11949389028724264],
                    'income_from_co_before_it': [31937678000.0,
                                                 0.02956142491216258],
                    'income_from_co_before_tax_si': [8966831000.0,
                                                     0.28700510835977744],
                    'income_tax': [4513369000.0, -0.3081478134092464],
                    'interest_expense': [3568241000.0, 0.9829135301368052],
                    'interest_income': [None, None],
                    'marketing_selling_etc': [19552502000.0,
                                              0.24008657043304116],
                    'net_income': [27424309000.0, 0.11949389028724264],
                    'net_income_atcss': [26220721000.0, 0.14906806875410045],
                    'net_income_atms_interest': [1203588000.0,
                                                 -0.2826994512917915],
                    'net_interest_expense': [3568241000.0, 0.9829135301368052],
                    'operating_income': [23451091000.0, -0.003255017899346956],
                    'othr_revenues': [None, None],
                    'preferred_dividend': [0.0, None],
                    'rad_expenses': [14962799000.0, 0.2737968808540811],
                    'report_annual': 2018,
                    'report_date': 1546185600004,
                    'report_name': '2018年FY',
                    'report_type_code': 596001,
                    'revenue': [371092421000.0, 0.2776851589186339],
                    'sales_cost': [309929371000.0, 0.3038187579796379],
                    'sd': '2018-01-01',
                    'share_of_earnings_of_affiliate': [-480244000.0,
                                                       -1.9133899600975308],
                    'total_basic_earning_common_ps': [6.18,
                                                      0.10554561717352413],
                    'total_compre_income': [26571677000.0, 0.33800831224856964],
                    'total_compre_income_atcss': [25620461000.0,
                                                  0.38309049519201155],
                    'total_compre_income_atms': [951216000.0,
                                                 -0.28751067367758754],
                    'total_dlt_earnings_common_ps': [6.07, 0.16955684007707125],
                    'total_net_income_atcss': [26220721000.0,
                                               0.14906806875410045],
                    'total_operate_expenses': [37711959000.0,
                                               0.29130215356164646],
                    'total_operate_expenses_si': [-371583000.0,
                                                  -2.4229614208334866],
                    'total_revenue': [371092421000.0, 0.2776851589186339]},
                   {'ctime': 1541759982000,
                    'ed': '2018-09-30',
                    'gross_profit': [42479000000.0, 0.11966577927726087],
                    'income_from_co': [20571000000.0, 0.15088956025511915],
                    'income_from_co_before_it': [24813000000.0,
                                                 0.07648590021691974],
                    'income_from_co_before_tax_si': [8885000000.0,
                                                     0.3284988038277512],
                    'income_tax': [4242000000.0, -0.1804482225656878],
                    'interest_expense': [None, None],
                    'interest_income': [None, None],
                    'marketing_selling_etc': [13734000000.0,
                                              0.17124339075558587],
                    'net_income': [20571000000.0, 0.15088956025511915],
                    'net_income_atcss': [19816000000.0, 0.18361008242742802],
                    'net_income_atms_interest': [755000000.0,
                                                 -0.3330388692579505],
                    'net_interest_expense': [2147000000.0, 0.8669565217391304],
                    'operating_income': [15928000000.0, -0.02652487470969319],
                    'othr_revenues': [None, None],
                    'preferred_dividend': [0.0, None],
                    'rad_expenses': [10670000000.0, 0.22629582806573956],
                    'report_annual': 2018,
                    'report_date': 1538236800000,
                    'report_name': '2018年Q9',
                    'report_type_code': 596007,
                    'revenue': [257064000000.0, 0.24513332203143542],
                    'sales_cost': [214585000000.0, 0.2733805692041112],
                    'sd': '2018-01-01',
                    'share_of_earnings_of_affiliate': [None, None],
                    'total_basic_earning_common_ps': [4.67,
                                                      0.12259615384615379],
                    'total_compre_income': [None, None],
                    'total_compre_income_atcss': [None, None],
                    'total_compre_income_atms': [None, None],
                    'total_dlt_earnings_common_ps': [4.6, 0.2137203166226912],
                    'total_net_income_atcss': [19816000000.0,
                                               0.18361008242742802],
                    'total_operate_expenses': [26551000000.0,
                                               0.23052324234138202],
                    'total_operate_expenses_si': [None, None],
                    'total_revenue': [257064000000.0, 0.24513332203143542]}],
          'org_type': 1,
          'quote_name': '日月光半导体',
          'sas': '国际会计准则',
          'statuses': None,
          'tip': '日月光半导体财年为每年的1月1日至12月31日，最新披露财报所属2020财年。'},
 'error_code': 0,
 'error_description': ''}
```